# Having trouble storing Python API JSON values to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, api

Python pulls data in JSON via API, but when trying to store into PostgreSQL I get a message that byte indices must be integers or slices, not a string.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "umbrella-import.py", line 32, in <module>
    my_data = [item[field] for field in fields]
  File "umbrella-import.py", line 32, in <listcomp>
    my_data = [item[field] for field in fields]
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I've tried changing from [] to {}.  I believe this is where you create dictionaries with strings?  I've also tried removing a "tuple" option when running cursor.execute.

It seems like there's something that needs updated between the list being created and the for loop.

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "devops", password = "password", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432", database = "umbrella")
cursor = connection.cursor()

fields = [
        'customerId', #Customer ID Number
        'customerName', #Customer Name
]

for item in response:
    my_data = [item[field] for field in fields]
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO umbrelladata VALUES (%s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(insert_query, tuple(my_data))
    connection.commit()

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

customerId is a number and can be stored as an integer.  customerName is just as it says - the name of a customer.  I believe this is where the break is?

In this script I'm trying to download customer ID numbers and customer names and store them in the Postgresql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON response is in the form of byte, and the error occurs when you try to access the dict item -

> my_data = [item[field] for field in fields]

So convert the data to dict using  -

```
import json
response=json.loads(response)
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks!  I had a few other issues with the script, but this was where I was stuck.